# NetworkStream threaded bottleneck

Tags: .net, sockets, networking, tcpclient, tpl-dataflow

I've been working on a server that receive requests from another server, calculate the value then return the result, all over TCP.

I'm quite new to backend developing. Last month, from 20000 responses per second to 80000, I've learnt a lot and applied them to this server: Pre allocation of byte[] buffer, non-alloc api calls, TPL Dataflow, Threading.

Basically, all the processing is now move into the Processing pipeline, the network receiving/sending is on their own single thread.

However, the overall performance is still limited by network IO, which is implemented with TCPClient.

## Implementation

- The NetworkStream R/W method used are blocking ones. Read 4 bytes first to get the length, 2 bytes for header, then N bytes for the message body.
- I use byte[] buffer wrapper object, named with *BufferSegmentPointer*. These objects is pre-initialized with a byte[] of certain length (>2048).
- The *BufferSegmentPointer* are transferred along TPL Dataflow pipeline, once a request is processed, the result is Buffer.BlockCopy() into the buffer, the used byte[] range is logged on it, then it'd be sent to NET OUTPUT through the pipeline, so NetworkStream.Write() just know what to write.
- The processing segment of the pipeline is a TransformBlock with MaxDegreeOfParallism set to Enviromnet.ProcessorCount - 2.

## Test Statistics

The program is simply a pipeline of **IN** > **PROCESSING** > **OUT**.

Which can be splitted into 5 segments:

**NET IN** > **IN Transfer** > **PROCESSING** > **Out Transfer** > **NET OUT**

> Noted that the following test result of VM is limited due to the test client on VM can not send enough request. **This is my bottleneck now.** The NetworkStream IO thread R/W is too slow.
>
> Noted that if I bundle tens of request into one NetworkStream.Write() call, it performs noticeably better, but it's meaningless because requests is never bundled in actual production scenario.
>
> Noted that, if I simply write a 2GB byte[] from test client, and receive it with the server, it cost 0.8 seconds. (All the tests mentioned in this post are performed on localhost.)

---

#### Test 1: TCP I

> 1000000 request of 702 bytes sent by test client in a loop.
>
> Stopwatch started on first one received, stop when all received.

O > X > X > X > X
(Not transferred through Dataflow, counted once received)

**Result**

- **12.99s** on ESXi VM 2.4GHz * 12
- **5.86s** on i5-7500 3.4GHz * 4

---

#### Test 2: TCP O

> For testing the writing throughput.
>
> 1000000 NetworkStream.Write() call of N bytes.
>
> Stopwatch started just before first one sent, stop when all sent.

X > X > X > X > O

**Result**

- **8.42s** N=653 on ESXi VM 2.4GHz * 12
- **4.75s** N=577, on i5-7500 3.4GHz * 4

---

#### Test 3: TCP IO

> 1000000 request of 702 bytes sent by test client in a loop.
>
> 1000000 response, 500~700 bytes because random result used.
>
> Stopwatch started just before first request sent by the test client, stop when all responses received.

O > X > X > X > O
(Request not transferred through Dataflow, counted once received)
(Response is created and convert to byte[] in advance, just write it once whenever a request is received)

**Result**

- **11.7s** On ESXi VM 2.4GHz * 12
- **5.74s** on i5-7500 3.4GHz * 4

---

#### Test 4: Local Processing

> 1000000 request of 702 bytes, generated by the server it self.
>
> No responses, once a processing call is done, the processed counter++.
>
> Stopwatch started just before first request feed into the pipeline, stop when processed counter reach 1000000.

X > O > O > X > X

**Result**

- **6.89s** on ESXi VM 2.4GHz * 12
- **8.28s** on i5-7500 3.4GHz * 4

---

#### Test 5: Production Test

> Processing included.
> 1000000 request, 702 bytes sent by the test client in a loop.
>
> 1000000 response, 500~700 bytes because random result used.
>
> Stopwatch started just before first request sent by the test client, stop when all responses received.

O > O > O > O > O

**Result**

- **18.6s** on ESXi VM 2.4GHz * 12
- **11.8s** on i5-7500 3.4GHz * 4

## My questions

1. Is this <100 mb/s throughput normal?
2. Could non-blocking (async) calls help?
3. Is it possible that SAEA (SocketAsyncEventArgs) could beat TCPClient? I saw that the socket methods will try to use SAEA if possible, and TCPClient is just a wrapper......
4. Do you have any assumption that where may be the bottleneck?
5. My supervisor can send more then 300000/s request (>200mb/s) with JAVA, is it really JAVA out performance .NET that much or it's me being stupid?
6. Due to the NetworkStream R/W performs better on my office PC (i5) compared to the VM, I believe the NetworkStream is limited by single core (thread) performance (is this assumption true?), but I need to know why is it so slow? Does it have to be so slow?